# Dropdowns work locally in production but don't work on real server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this application.js
And when I run my app locally with env production dropdowns work fine. But after deploy to a real server they stopped working.

```
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.turbolinks   
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

How can I fix this?

up1

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullapplication-c6f1be54480428c9ab047aa15b1a5d07.js:4 
window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.plugins.setLangapplication-c6f1be54480428c9ab047aa15b1a5d07.js:21 (anonymous function)
```

up2

I dev env I have a lot of errors

[image]

**UP3**

**When I move ckeditor directory to public there're no errors.**

Comment: Did you precompile your assets on the real server?

Comment: I tried both. 1) precompiled locally and 2) compiled on server. No result.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @railsr Do you use any ckeditor plugins?

Comment: @JiříPospíšil, only youtube plugin. But I don't think dropdowns problem's related to ck editor

Comment: @railsr If ckeditor throws an error, it will halt the execution of the other scripts (you require bootstrap later). I might be completely off but I suspect the error has something to do with casing (upcase/downcase letters) in the name of the youtube plugin (I assume the prod server is running linux with case sensitive file system). Make sure that the casing is correct - the folder with plugin matches the registration of the plugin.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil folder and plugin name now matches, but I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of things but ended up removing turbolinks completely.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and tried many of the answers found here untill it worked. I suggest deleting the public and tmp folders (or their content) and deploying like that, then precompile the assets in your server. That and fiddling with the order of the requires worked for me. Hope it helps.